# Why is the value of variable is empty in for loop not working?

Tags: windows, batch-file

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "SERVER[1]=server1.a.com"        
set "SERVER[2]=server2.b.com"   
set "SERVER[3]=server3.c.com"
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,3) DO (

     FOR /F "delims=" %%j IN ('Psexec -s -c -f \\%%SERVER[%%i]%% c:\temp\printerCount.bat ^| findstr /B /E  "[0-9]*"') DO (

    set today=%%j
         ECHO today:%today%
    )
)
```

i get the output displayed fine without the outer for loop :

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN ('Psexec -s -c -f \\server1.a.com c:\temp\printerCount.bat ^| findstr /B /E  "[0-9]*"') DO set today=%%i
ECHO today:%today%
pause
```

Comment: Search SO for `delayed expansion`. It's #1 FAQ in batch.

Comment: sorry edited delayed expansion was enabled for both. the scripts.. just edited the upper one

Comment: OK, i just changed %today% to !today! and it works not sure why

Comment: @munish, because that is how Microsoft developed delayed expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point with `delayed expansion` is that it's not just some incantation which automatically changes the way that variables are extracted from the environment. It's an extension that, when in effect, actually extracts `!var!` as the *current* value of the variable whereas `%var%` is replaced in the parsing phase by the *then*-current value of the variable, hence it appears unchanged as the loops operates and changes `var`.

IOW,

```
     ECHO today:%today%
```

should be

```
     ECHO today:!today!
```

since the value of the variable `today` is changed within the loop. `%today%` will be the value of `today` *when the loop was encountered*.

In your case, `today` was not defined, hence has a value of *nothing* when the loop was encountered, so `%today%` is replaced by *nothing* when the loop is executed.